# PHP URL array returns result from previous routing array

Tags: php, arrays, url, routes

I use URL routing on my website and this is the code I use:

```
/* TURN FULL URL INTO --> /example/example2/example3 */
function getCurrentUri()
{
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    return $uri;
}
$base_url = getCurrentUri();
$routes = array();
$routes = explode('/', $base_url);
foreach($routes as $route)
{
    if(trim($route) != ''){
        array_push($routes, $route);
    }
}
```

For some reason it outputs the following when using `var_dump()` on `$routes[0]`, `$routes[1]`, `$routes[2]` and `$routes[3]`. This is while being on the following website: `http://localhost/tutorials/`

```
string '' (length=0)
string 'tutorials' (length=9)
string 'tutorials' (length=9)
null
```

How can I solve this routing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly:

1. You created array variable `$routes`.
2. Then you fill that array with strings from `explode('/', $base_url)`.
3. You iterate that array and if string is not `''`, then you push that string onto the end of array.

To avoid this, you can use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) instead of `array_push()` and change condition from `trim($route) != ''` to `trim($route) === '' || trim($route) === null`. Second condition is needed to remove `null` element from array.

Or you can assign `explode('/', $base_url)` to different variable, e.g. `$explodedUrls` and iterave over its.

Comment: Does this solve the problem that `$routes[0]` is equal to `tutorials` in this case? and that `$routes[1]` is NULL

Comment: `trim($route) === null` removes `null` from array so yes, it solves the problem. About `tutorials`, it is the part of URL so it stay in the array. Base url should `www.foo.bar` and then result of `$routes` is empty array. But if your url is `www.foo.bar/baz` then `$routes[0] === 'baz`. To solve problem with directory (like I assume), use virtual host.